# webpack context and resolve.modules not resolving node_modules

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to introduce webpack into a legacy project with the following folder structure:

```
-web
    -project
       - webpack.config.js
       - package.json
    -src
       - client.js
```

Everytime I run webpack --config webpack.config.js in the project folder I get the following error: ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader\ in ......\web.

I set the context to the web folder because it is the parent of the config and the src. I also added both the src and node modules to the resolve.modules property. Is there a configuration that I'm missing?

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const webpack = require('webpack');


const babelConfig = {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "add-module-exports",
    "transform-export-extensions"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": []
    }
  }
};
const base = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
const project = path.resolve(base, 'project');
const src = path.resolve(base, 'src');

module.exports = {
  context: base,
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(project, 'node_modules'), src],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  entry: {
    plp: path.resolve(src, 'client.js')
  },
  devtool: '#inline-source-map',
  output: {
    filename     : '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + "/../dist"
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    modules: true,
    reasons: true,
    errorDetails: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: [src],
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: babelConfig
      }]
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __DEVELOPMENT__: !isProduction,
      __DEVTOOLS__: !isProduction
    }),

    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats\.json$/)
  ]
};
```

The package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-es2016/-/babel-preset-es2016-6.22.0.tgz",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we have the whole file structure ? At least the package.json  + node_modules

Comment: I added the package.json. The whole file structure is as described in the post. There are no more folders that are related to the webpack setup

Comment: Where is your package.json.

Comment: added :) thanks for your time

Comment: Did you try resolveLoader: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1083#issuecomment-103820257 ?

Comment: If I add the resolveLoader config, I get ERROR in Entry module not found: Error in ./websrc/client.js Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to  "......\web\src"